# Using same model for two different forms but with different validation rule

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have a model with validation rule like this

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('oldPassword,newPassword', 'required'),
        array('newPassword','length','max'=>64, 'min'=>6),
        array('newPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'confirmPassword'),
        array('confirmPassword', 'safe'),
    );
}
```

I want to use this same model for two different forms. In one form oldPassword validation is required & in the other not required. is this possible?

Comment: Strictly speaking, validation rules aren't a model.  A model tends to refer to something such as a product, a user, a blog post, a comment or some other individual set of data in your system.  A model can (and should) have rules to ensure you can't put it into an inconsistent state, but rules on their own aren't a model.  you could argue that a form is a model, and the rules to validate it are part of the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mind reading [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/form.model)? if you still dont get it after that there is a [wiki about it](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios)

Please try to do some research before posting a question